# Mysql large table stucks on update or delete query

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin, query-timeout

In Mysql one table is of 10GB and if i select data it will run very fast but as soon as I do any insert or delete operation it stucks on select operation after that. How to resolve this issue that if I do any update or delete it stucks on select after that. Note: there is one column long-text in that table.

Comment: What engine are you using? Are you sure you are not using transactions?

Comment: No transactions.. I am using phpmyadmin for Mysql database.

Comment: when you delete or update are you using an indexed field to do that?

Comment: inodb is the engine

Comment: no indexing was done there.. It is just a heavy table and if I select any data from that table it runs fine.. but as soon as i insert or delete any row with some condition it runs fine but after this select operation stucks

Comment: 10GB is a large table, you should consider indexing. Are you sure you are not catching your select?